# Closing a window which pops up while running batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ant, automation, build-process

There is this application build process that I am trying to automate. For this i wrote a java file, which runs every 24 hours. 
A batch file is called from here that runs the application build whenever it is called.

I've run into a small problem, when the build fails due to incomplete or invalid files, a window pops up which tells me to look at the logs.
Since I haven't written the build files, I'm not really sure where this gets created from. I wanted to know if I can close this window while the process runs from the bat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible using `taskkill`, but you'd have to devise a filter that would ideally *only* match the process displaying the window and *never* match any other process. Something like:

```
taskkill /im program.exe
```

or maybe:

```
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq title*"
```

You might also want to include the `/f` flag for forceful termination.

You'd also have to try and make sure that the `taskkill` command doesn't run too quickly and precede the creation of the popup window. You could try to query for the existence of such a process/window; your best bet here is probably `wmic`. Maybe:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set title=Notepad
set pid=
for /f %%i in ('wmic process where "caption like \"%%!title!%%\"" get processid^| findstr /r [0-9]') do @set pid=%%i
if "!pid!" neq "" taskkill /f /pid !pid!
```

There's no guarantee this will always work, but it's probably the best you can do.

Comment: Will give this a try. I'm very new to batch programming & automation. So might be a while until i actually get this working :)

Comment: awesome. That cleared things more...thanks a ton :) I'll comment back here once i've tried this